# I need help understanding the issue with this nested if else

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple program to differentiate even and odd numbers and apply a function to them based upon their values, I try to run this and I get an "else without previous if" on both of my "else" statements

I submitted this to my class help forum and they said to include my if statements with brackets, which I have done. (possibly incorrectly)

```
int output = 0;
if (Input < 0); 
{
    cout << "0" << endl:
} else 
{
    if (Input % 2 == 0);
    {
        output = (Input / 2);
        cout << output << endl;
    }
}
else 
{   if (output = (3 * Input) + 1);
    {
        cout << output << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’ on both of the else statements
```

Comment: Look at your second if statement.  How many } are there after it?

Comment: You have a semicolon after the close of the parentheses after the first "if".    That effectively terminates the "if" statement making the following "else" nonsensical.  Remove that semicolon

Comment: You have semi-colons at the end of all the `if` statements.  Remove them.

Answer (score 1):

If you align your indentation properly, the problem becomes clear.

```
if (Input < 0)
{
    cout << "0" << endl:
}
else 
{
    if (Input % 2 == 0)
    {
        output = (Input / 2);
        cout << output << endl;
    }
}
else 
{
    if (output = (3 * Input) + 1)
    {
        cout << output << endl;
    }
}
```

There are two `else` in succession. It makes no sense.

Also, you are not supposed to close `if ()` statements with `;`, if you do that you are effectively telling the compiler that this `if ()` doesn't trigger anything (it's been closed with no code associated to it).

Comment: Let's hear it for [Allman Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style)! Makes scoping bugs all but vanish! Handles even the toughest stains!

Comment: Okay, so two else is a no go. I removed the second else and found that the program almost works. However, from there how would I make the final "if" conditional on the second "if" not being executed? Right now I find that I get a two number output  and the final "if" is always being executed. Furthermore, my program won't run at all without the `;` present at the end of the `endl` is that a byproduct of poor code design?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve. I suppose the final `else` should belong to `if (Input % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I didn't need a second else at all, instead I just needed to use a relational operator as the condition of my third if statement. Have a nice day!